# Ionic Capacitor Admob simple example fails with type?

Tags: ionic-framework, capacitor, ionic5

I am trying to integrate the Capacitor Admob by the example

```
https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/admob
```

but

```
import { Admob } from '@ionic-native/admob';

...

constructor(private admob: Admob)
```

fails with

```
[ng]     ERROR in src/app/map/map.page.ts:81:30 - error TS2749: 'Admob' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here.
[ng]     
[ng]     81               private admob: Admob,
```

?
Why should the example break?

Answer (score 1):

I have run into this "gotcha" as well. You need to import `import { Admob } from '@ionic-native/admob/ngx';` as this is the portion that indicates to import the angular specific version.

Comment: Thanks, I don't know how often I've already run into this one and seem to not learn... :)

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs, "Capacitor Not compatible."

This may be of use?

[Capacitor AdMob](https://github.com/capacitor-community/admob)